# force application to terminate in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone application which is completely based on web data.

If it is not connected to the internet, the application is of no use.

So, I want to terminate the application when connection is not found.

```
NSURL *tmpURl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@search.php",[iGolfAppDelegate getServerPath]]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tmpURl];
    con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(con){
        myWebData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];    
    } else { 
        //Yes I will provide two buttons on alertview "retry" & "close", & when user
        //taps on "close" => application should terminate.
        // i will send alertview & when user taps on button close then
        // what to write for terminating application?
        // Ok Ok. Don't terminate. User will terminate.
        // user is owner of iPhone 
        // let him choose what to do
        // wait till wifi connects
    }
```

The question is how to terminate the application?

Is `exit(0)` only the option for terminating application or is there any other option available?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application (though the accepted answer there is "wrong").

Comment: Then what should be the answer?

Comment: The correct answer is "don't do this".  It is explicitly against the published UI guidelines.  Several commenters here have offered suggestions for what to do instead.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application Voted to close.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apple is is absolutely clear about this topic:

> There is no API provided for
>   gracefully terminating an iPhone
>   application. Under the iPhone OS, the
>   user presses the Home button to close
>   applications. Should your application
>   have conditions in which it cannot
>   provide its intended function, the
>   recommended approach is to display an
>   alert for the user that indicates the
>   nature of the problem and possible
>   actions the user could take - turning
>   on WiFi, enabling Location Services,
>   etc. Allow the user to terminate the
>   application at their own discretion.

See [Technical Q&A QA1561](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1561.html)

Comment: And then the OS got "multitasking" :) The limited implementation of it causes problems for the user. I trust the user to know when he has finished using an app and when he just wants to hide it, but all the app ever gets is viewWillEnterBackground. There's no problem getting an iPhone in a mode where there's two-second delays just using the phone itself, due to all the apps hogging resources. So I think now there is at least one reason to have an Exit-button in an app, even if for the asker's example it would not be a classy solution. ;)

Comment: Totally disagree. There is no need for an Exit button at all. But there definitely *IS* a need for a proper exit/restart function from the developer perspective - to reset database, to test things out, invalid unknown state (prevent data corruption if user continued usage.) etc. we're left with just crashing the app forcefully outright for that, which sucks.

Answer (score 10):

You might consider informing the user that they cannot use your application without an active network connection.  Just terminating the application outright seems like a very unfriendly way of doing this; the user will simply see the app "disappear".

Every well-behaved app I've seen will at least give a notification before terminating.

Comment: Very much this.  Tell the user that the app doesn't work without a connection, and let them kill it themselves.

Comment: Also, it's not impossible for the network to simply drop out for a few seconds.  It would be super frustrating to use such an app in an area with a spotty connection.

Answer (score 6):

I would advise you to reconsider for 3 reasons

1. It may appear that your app crashed.
2. The user may get an internet connection while your app is up. In this case a 'Retry' would be best.
3. I think Apple may actually not accept the app if it does that. It is for sure not what they would do if an Apple application needed an internet connection, and they do test to see what an app will do without a connection.

If (for whatever reason)you do want to do it you can use.

```
exit(0);
```

Comment: Yes I will provide two buttons on alertview "retry" & "close", & when user taps on "close" => application should terminate.

Comment: In that case, you should have one button: "retry".  Every application on the iPhone already has a "close" button -- the hardware home button -- and there's no need for you to implement another.

Answer (score 5):

You could always just divide by zero. As a bonus, the implementation would reflect what a good idea this is.

Comment: No. here application will terminate by an exception - "divide by zero".

Comment: So now you're upset that the application will terminate? For the love of pants, man, make up your mind!

Comment: Looking at your reputation, I take this answer as a joke: +1

Comment: It's a joke + it actually answers the question "is there any other option available?" as well as it can be answered given that this is something you shouldn't do. The opportunity to do both at once so seldom arises I had to take it.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helpful
[[NSThread mainThread] exit];

Answer (score 2):

If you terminate it will look like your app has crashed!

Best to put up a message saying that there is no internet connection and give them an option to retry (in case they can get an internet connection), or choose to quite it themselves

Comment: But client need this, I know you are right but for us Client is "Our Boss" & "Boss is always right."

Comment: In this case, the boss is wrong.  Period.  Show them the text that **Nikolai Ruhe** posted in his answer.

Comment: @sagar If your "Boss" insists, point him/her to Apple’s documentation. Apple strongly discourages terminating an app programatically. I provided a link in my answer.

Comment: @sagar: Your boss's idea will likely get his app rejected from the App Store. Blindly saying "the boss is right" when you know what you're doing will not achieve his likely goal (having a marketable app) isn't respectful, it's passive-aggressive.

Comment: @Chuck, I think there may be cultural issues clouding things here. Overall I agree that you have to draw the line somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this. Take a look at "Stopping" in [the Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/HandleTasks/HandleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH16-SW3) as you could possibly fail for submitting an App that does this, or at the very least provide for a strange user experience.

The link also shows the correct way to handle this, as in the iTunes Music Store app.

Answer (score 1):

Your App will be rejected if you terminate when you cannot reach the Internet.

Sorry.

-t