# iPhone SDK Quitting

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have found many apps where you can press a button or something similar and the application will terminate and bring you back to the home screen. How would I do this?

Comment: I downvoted this question because the subject is totally not to the point.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application

Answer (score 1):

exit(0);

this can exit the app .

again, the best way I think will be like as follows:

```
    //@step invoke the normal routine applicationWillTerminate
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)]) 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) withObject:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}
//@step force quite app
kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
```

I got it from other post on the overflow :D

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6928-exit-application.html

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
```

Comment: That is not a public API method.

Comment: the question didnt ask for a public api method.

Comment: Did so ask for public - what is iPhone sdk 3.0? if not public.