# Can an iphone app shut itself down programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want the user to start the app and leave it running. At one point, the app will finish what it is doing and will shut itself down.
How can I do that in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application

Comment: @ChiragKothiya, thank you for your edit: I've approved it. Just note that instead of using `<br>`, you can use the markup syntax of two spaces and a new line. See my subsequent edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using method:

```
exit(0);
```

However, be warned that Human Interface Guideliness discourage the use of this function, as it  looks as if the application had crashed. The good solution for such a usecase is to prompt user that the application has finished working, and that he may close it now.

Hope this helps,
Paul

Comment: Apple does not like apps committing suicide:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application/356342#356342

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul. I found another thread at [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)
Perhaps Apple doesnt like applications committing suicide ;)