# Remotely Closing the App

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have a button in my UI and was wondering if you are able to close the app and exit to the homescreen if you press it. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is just like you click on the middle button

Comment: This is bad design because it very easy to accidentally hit buttons on a touch interface. I have an eye injury that destroyed my depth perception so I hit the screen more often than I intend. This had made me sensitive to the problem but everyone experiences it to a lesser degree. You users will find themselves quitting accidentally a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

Answer (score 5):

You can always call exit(0) but it is against Apple's design guidelines to close applications programatically. The recommended way is when the user press the home button.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your thoughts for doing this, but 
try explaining why or at least think it over again :)

A snippet from the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf)

> iPhone applications should never quit
>   programmatically because doing so
>   looks like a crash to the user. There
>   may be times, however, when external
>   circumstances prevent your application
>   from functioning as intended. The best
>   way to handle this is to display an
>   attractive screen that describes the
>   problem and suggests how users can
>   correct it. This helps users in two
>   ways: ■   It provides feedback that
>   reassures users that there’s nothing
>   wrong with your application ■ It puts
>   users in control, letting them decide
>   whether they want to take corrective
>   action and continue using your
>   application or press the Home button
>   and open a different application

Answer (score 1):

This method works also `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];`, but as mentioned shouldn't be used for distribution on the AppStore.