# how to minimize application on button click in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, background

I have one task to developer an application in which user can press the "MINIMIZE" button from my application the application should become in background stare and it should not be terminated by my iOS because i am sending some data from my application to server in background mode also.

so my question is how to minimize my application from button of my app?
and the application should not be close automatically from iOs.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot control whether or when your application is terminated. Welcome to iOS.

Comment: If your app is performing a background task, the OS won't kill it unless it has to. But like Michael Petrotta says, you don't have much say in the end.

Comment: @keyboardP thanks dude, but i am sending user location to server but after sometime my application is going to be crashed in background. did you have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through code, you can ONLY EXIT from app through code.
refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086465/close-minimize-app-from-code) Stack Overflow question.