# Restart iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force iphone app to restart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399611/force-iphone-app-to-restart-programmatically)

I have an alert popping up informing the user to restart the app, in order to change the theme.

However, if the user selects OKAY, from the alert, I would like to automatically restart the app.  Is this possible or allowed by Apple?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. You can exit the app if you want using exit(1); but is highly discouraged. Why do you want to restart your app? There should be other workarounds to that.

Comment: Thanks, I had my doubts if this was possible

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't relaunch your app. You should consider a better approach to themes.

Comment: Thanks, but not possible in my case