# Reload AppDelegate Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have an appdelegate that contains a lot of objects, which are initialized and
accessed from various places in the App.
I have a view controllers also in the appdelegate, and at some point in the Application, i need all of that to be reinitialized like the app is firstly run. and the appdelegate is firstly initialized.
How can i achieve that?
the `[appDelegate finishLoadingWithOptions:nil]` didn't work for me, because it doesn't 
reinitialize the view controller which i connect using IBOutlet.
Please don't advise me to do it differently, because i am working on
project that is not of my work, and poorly documented.

Comment: Fixing it the right way is probably going to go better for you than doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you basically want to totally restart your app. If that's the case, [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399611/force-iphone-app-to-restart-programmatically) is going to be your best bet (I'm marking this as a duplicate as well for that reason).

*That said*, I think it would be well worth spending some time pulling out the data from your app delegate into something more appropriate. The application delegate is certainly *convenient* for storing data used throughout your app, but it's not really *appropriate*.

I know you say *"please don't advise me to do it differently"*, but even though it's not your own code you could still re-factor it and make it better. Hopefully you'll be able to!