# How to force a Flutter application restart (in production mode)?

Tags: flutter

In *production mode*, is there a way to force a full restart of the application (I am **not** talking about a hot reload at development time!).

Practical use cases:

- At initialization process the application detects that there is no network connection.  The lack of network connectivity might have prevented a correct start up (e.g. loading of external resource such as JSON files...).
- During the initial handshaking, new versions of some important resources need to be downloaded (kind of update).

In both use cases, I would like the application to proceed with a full restart, rather than having to build a complex logic at the ApplicationState level.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You could wrap your whole app into a statefulwidget. And when you want to restart you app, rebuild that statefulwidget with a child that possess a different `Key`.

This would make you loose the whole state of your app.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    RestartWidget(
      child: MaterialApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RestartWidget({this.child});

  final Widget child;

  static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartWidgetState>().restartApp();
  }

  @override
  _RestartWidgetState createState() => _RestartWidgetState();
}

class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyedSubtree(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

In this example you can reset your app from everywhere using `RestartWidget.restartApp(context)`.

Comment: THIS SHOULD NOT BE THE CORRECT ANSWER as it does not "restart the app" at the OS level.  For example, you may need to do this due to the OS memory issues, and to clear it, only completely removing the App from memory and restarting it will help.  I have seen examples where this can be done on the android level in the Manifest. Google it.

Comment: @JamesGardiner Then what is your solution to this problem?

Comment: But I have encountered one problem with this approach. Whenever I hot reload the application it starts again from the root. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: ok, my bad I was adding a `statefulwidget` inside `RestartWidget()` method but now I just added `MaterialApp()` inside `RestartWidget()`. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way to make all stateful child widgets reset themselves as well? By "reset" I mean create new instances (running the constructor, initstate, etc)? Or do we need to wrap each child widget in its own `RestartWidget`? If so, is there a way to make it more generic (i.e. get rid of the static method so it can be applied to multiple widgets)? Or better yet, is there a way to truly restart the app, like the `Flutter Hot Restart` button does?

Comment: @Spectarion Using [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) and writing OS-specific restart for both ios and android would be my solution. [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4399611/8608146) [android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6609414/8608146) But this answer is better as it does not restart the app and just rebuilds the whole flutter widget tree.

Comment: ca you update the code,since flutter 1.1213  got 'ancestorStateOfType' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use findAncestorStateOfType instead.'TypeMatcher' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. TypeMatcher has been deprecated because it is no longer used in framework(only in deprecated methods). This feature was deprecated after v1.12.1..

Comment: The above comment regarding Flutter 1.12.1 deprecation needs the line changed to `final _RestartWidgetState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<State<RestartWidget>>();` based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448102/ancestorstateoftype-is-deprecated-use-findancestorstateoftype-instead]

Comment: echoing on @MagnusW 's comment. I have an method which is called in the build method of my main window right before RestartWidget is returned. any way of having that function called during the restart as well?

Comment: is their anyway to achieve this by a widget which is not a child of the RestartWidget?
I am able to achieve the same by the direct child of the RestartWidget.

Comment: code between `main() {` and `runApp(` won't get called, so if there is any init code there, it may have to be moved or called right before `restartApp()`

Comment: It worked great for me. But I added `navigatorKey` in MaterialApp(), and it stop working. Any suggestions? I used `navigatorKey` for pushing screens without context.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time by this answer, thank you so much Remi @remi Rousselet

Comment: For those, who needs to restart app without context, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600918/4693979

Comment: I can confirm that this rebuilds constant widgets down the widget tree, this is beautiful thank you Remi.

Comment: @J.Diaz have you found any solution for navigatorKey issue?

Comment: Anyone who wants to restart the application from OS level can use this package:

Comment: [RestartFromOS](https://pub.dev/packages/restartfromos)

Comment: @J.Diaz Just use: `setState(() { navigatorKey = GlobalKey(); });`

Answer (score 57):

The [flutter_phoenix package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) is based on [Rémi Rousselet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode#answer-50116077), making it even simpler.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then when you need to restart the app, just call:

```
Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```

Comment: I tried this package but it doesn't work for me the Objects do not reset. Or is it that it doesn't reset the objects?

Comment: Didn't work for me, nothing happens when i call rebirth() method

Comment: Not working anymore https://github.com/mobiten/flutter_phoenix/issues/20

Answer (score 25):

I developed the [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) plugin, with +200 likes in pub.dev, to restart the whole app with **native APIs**.

---

**Update May 25, 2023:**

The package now supports all Android, iOS and Web platforms.

Comment: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method restartApp on channel restart)

Is it because of Flutter 2 (I tried to used it on 1.22.6) or something else?

Comment: Please migrate it to null safety, it is a very useful plugin

Comment: Do you happen to know a solution for linux?

Comment: But does it work for iOS devices

Comment: Great package. Worked for me for flutter web

Comment: @K.Amanov It is on null safety.

Comment: @hemandroid Not yet. But I'm working on solutions.

Comment: Great answer which is working perfectly for me

Comment: @hemandroid As version 1.2.0, now it supports iOS as well.

Answer (score 18):

I just want to add Regarding I have Tried @Remi answer which works great on most of the cases to restart the app. The only problem with the answer is that some things if you are doing Navigation route extensively you probably go to a state which It gives you an error like,
`The method 'restartApp' was called on null`.
To resolve this error you have to know the Context and use  `Navigator.of(context).pop();` multiples times back. For me, the solution is that just go to the initial route. It will inject all the states from a new. Where you want to restart just add this Line.

```
 Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,'/',(_) => false);
```

If you want to only restart a specific widget then the Remi solution is awesome. Thanks for the solution Remi though. It help me understand states in flutter.

Comment: After being confronted to the same problem, I must say that this solution is working great for me. Callable from anywhere and all it takes is one line. Keep it simple !

Comment: Yes, simple and meets the need.

Comment: This is the main solution actually

Comment: @Shahryar I cannot thank you enough, it is the best solution

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the runApp(new MyWidget) function to do something similar

This is what this function does:

Inflate the given widget and attach it to the screen.

The widget is given constraints during layout that force it to fill the entire screen. If you wish to align your widget to one side of the screen (e.g., the top), consider using the Align widget. If you wish to center your widget, you can also use the Center widget

Calling runApp again will detach the previous root widget from the screen and attach the given widget in its place. The new widget tree is compared against the previous widget tree and any differences are applied to the underlying render tree, similar to what happens when a StatefulWidget rebuilds after calling State.setState.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/runApp.html

Comment: The problem with this is that it may preserve the state

Comment: @RémiRousselet Then what is your solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey @RémiRousselet, I'm currently using this approach with scoped bloc pattern. Could you help me understand when this may preserve state? Congrats on the I/O announcement.

Comment: If you specify a `UniqueKey` to the widget passed to `runApp`, that should be fine. The worse is that it makes the widget that wants the refresh knows too much.

Comment: With the accepted answer, the refresh event do not know what the root widget is. With the `runApp` solution, one must know what that root widget is.

Comment: This doesn't work. Calling runapp again does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 8):

So simple [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_restart/example): flutter_restart

```
dependencies:
flutter_restart: ^0.0.3
```

to use:

```
void _restartApp() async {
  FlutterRestart.restartApp();
}
```

Comment: @PålBrattberg i used it in my project and its working fine.

Comment: Sorry about that sweeping comment. I run on iOS, Android, Web and macOS, and tried in macOS where it did not work. But for mobile, this is likely to work. I would recommend one of the pure-Flutter answers though, for the simple fact they are likely to work on more platforms.

Answer (score 7):

Thecnically this is not a restart but it will work for most of the scenarios:

```
// Remove any route in the stack
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => false);

// Add the first route. Note MyApp() would be your first widget to the app.
Navigator.push(
  context,
  CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyApp()),
);
```

Comment: this looks clean enough

Comment: I like this one, this was the simplest and most graceful for my needs.  I put this in a timer.

Answer (score 5):

I have found [Hossein's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9885611/hossein-yousefpour) [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) package also pretty useful for native restarts (not only on Flutter level).

To everyone having the MissingPluginException error, just reinstall the app again on the device, means that hot reload won't work. The app has native methods which need to compiled in the Android/iOS App.

Comment: Thanks, man. I think the package link in your answer has a problem. The correct link is: https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app

Comment: Just as an update, the package is updated to v1.2.0 and now it supports iOS as well.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to restart my app after logout.
so I used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix (flutter phoenix).
It worked for me.

1. Install flutter_phoenix by running this command on your terminal inside your flutter app directory.
    `$ flutter pub add flutter_phoenix`
2. Import it inside your "main.dart".
3. Wrap your root widget inside Phoenix.

```
     runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: MyApp()
  ));
```

4. Now you can call this wherever you want to restart your app :-
   `Phoenix.rebirth(context)`

**Note:** flutter_phoenix does not restart the app on OS level, it only restarts the app on app level.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above suggested methods and none of them worked and  i was using getx.
so i ended up modified the accepted answer with a delay as a workaround and it works now.

```
   class RestartAppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RestartAppWidget({this.child});

  final Widget child;

  static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartAppWidgetState>().restartApp();
  }

  @override
  _RestartAppWidgetState createState() => _RestartAppWidgetState();
}

class _RestartAppWidgetState extends State<RestartAppWidget> {
  bool restarting = false;

  void restartApp() async {
    restarting = true;   // restart variable is set to true
    setState(() {});
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300)).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        restarting = false; //restart variable is set to false
      });
    });
    // setState(() {
    //   key = UniqueKey();
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (restarting) {
      return SizedBox();   //an empty Sizedbox is displayed for 300 milliseconds you can add a loader if you want
    }
    return SizedBox(
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}`
```

wrap the root widget with RestartAppWidget

```
  runApp(RestartAppWidget(
      child: MyApp(),
    ))
```

you can use this code to restart the app at flutter level

```
RestartAppWidget.restartApp(Get.context);
```

Comment: You just needed to call 'Get.reset()' before calling the restartApp().

Comment: This seems a far better approach, nice

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow worked for me by navigating to the stateful widget which is called in the void main function located in main.dart, in my case that widget is called MyApp.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MyApp()), (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps-

1. Go to your terminal and type in the following:

```
flutter pub add flutter_restart
```

This will update some dependencies in pubspec.yaml file.

2. Import the following package in whichever file you want to implement the restart code-

```
import 'package:flutter_restart/flutter_restart.dart';
```

3. Create a void function

```
void _restartApp() async {
  await FlutterRestart.restartApp();
}
```

4. Write this wherever you want to start the app-

```
_restartApp();
```