# Is there a way to rebuild the whole app include const widgets in flutter project?

Tags: widget, flutter, constants, rebuild

In my Flutter project, to improve performance I created many `const` widgets, these widgets will not rebuild when their parent widgets rebuild.

But after the user changes language of the app, I need to rebuild the whole app to apply the text changes.

Is there a way to force the app to completely rebuild? Thanks, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There is, that is `Inheritedwidget`. Did you use `Localization` widget or made everything yourself? Because that widget provided by Flutter already handles everything

Comment: High is an adjective and cannot be used in the context: "to high performance". You should use "to improve performance" instead

Comment: Thank you @RémiRousselet, I made everything by myself. `Inheritedwidget` looks like not working for my situation.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English, thank you @01leo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes there is a way to do it. you have to do full restart (now it's called Hot Restart) in the code, the way to do it is to put your App inside a static widget(why static? because it'll be created once just to avoid the null or anything like that). and when you want to do full restart, just perform a hot-reload in that widget, after that it'll restart your app. you can use it from everywhere

here is the way :

1- first in main.dart, put the your App inside the Restart widget :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new HotRestartController(
    child: new MyApp()
  ));
}
```

2- write your hotRestartController inside the file :

```
class HotRestartController extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  HotRestartController({this.child});

  static performHotRestart(BuildContext context) {
    final _HotRestartControllerState state = context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_HotRestartControllerState>());
    state.performHotRestart();
  }

  @override
  _HotRestartControllerState createState() => new _HotRestartControllerState();
}

class _HotRestartControllerState extends State<HotRestartController> {
  Key key = new UniqueKey();

  void performHotRestart() {
    this.setState(() {
      key = new UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

3- anytime, anywhere you can import the main.dart, and call "performHotRestart" using:

```
HotRestartController.restartApp(context)
```

have fun !

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for

Comment: he is asking for "a way to force to rebuild the whole app", this is the way 

Comment: He's asking for a way to update all the `const` widget that depends on translations, not to _hard reset_ everything. Or else this is a duplicate question and I'll close it.

Comment: The answer you provided already exists here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode/50116077#50116077. It's literally the same code

Comment: ancestorStateOfType is deprecated,
please replace it with : final _HotRestartControllerState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HotRestartControllerState>();

Comment: Even though this is not what OP is asking for, I am glad I saw this answer as it opened to me another opportunity to solve this issue, via Remi's other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode/50116077#50116077

Answer (score 5):

'Inheritedwidget` is a solution to redraw any widget when the passed value change. Even stateless and const widgets.

For translations for example, flutter already provides an InheritedWidget, which you can bind to using `Localizations.of` method