# Logout from non-Widget class

Tags: flutter

My app makes multiple requests to the server.  Sometimes the server may ask the user to re-login, similar to this question:
[Flutter: how to force an application restart (in production mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode)

I could do something like this,

```
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

but I need to have a BuildContext for this.

Is there a way to get a current (most recently used) context while in a non-Widget class?  I know I can pass the context as an argument every time I'm making a server call, but I hope to find a less intrusive way to do this.

Comment: Each widget has its own `context`, assigned during the build phase. What criteria determines which of them is the "most recently used" one?

Comment: If you need the context, you have to pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are looking for `context` is because you'd like to get hold of the `Navigator`. (All the `Navigator.pushXXX` calls do a `Navigator.of(context)` under the hood to find the (typically) one and only navigator up near the top of the widget tree.)

If what you really want is just access to the navigator, there's another way to do this. Make your app stateful and put a global key in its state.

```
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

In the app's build (or top inherited widget's build), when you create the material app, pass it the key.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _SomeInherited(
      data: this,
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        title: 'Some Title',
        theme: someTheme,
        home: FrontPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, from the level of the app, you can use `navigatorKey.currentState.pushXXX`

Comment: Works great, thanks for the recipe!  I also noticed that the navigatorKey gives me access to  currentContext and currentWidget.