# Force MaterialApp "home" to be rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, scoped-model

I'm using the technique [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116077/930640) to "restart" my app. The problem is that the "home" page of my `MaterialApp` doesn't get recreated (it's `initState` is not executed on restart).

For this to happen, I have to briefly return something else than the `MaterialApp` from the `build` method in my app state.

```
class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = new UniqueKey();

  static bool isRestarting = false;

  void restartApp() {
    this.setState(() {
      isRestarting = true;
      key = new UniqueKey();
    });

    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (){
      this.setState(() {
        isRestarting = false;
        key = new UniqueKey();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if( _RestartWidgetState.isRestarting ) {
      return Container( ... );
    }
    else{
      return ScopedModel<MyModel>(
        model: myModel,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: MainScreen(),

          ...

        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Is there another/better way of doing this? It feels kind of sketchy.

Comment: Your RestartWidget is placed above MyApp right?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Correct. `MyAppState.initState` is executed, but `MainScreenState.initState` is not, unless I briefly switch out the entire layout for some other widget (the `Container( ... )`) and then back to the `MaterialApp`.