# Flutter:How to automatically clear my TextFields?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to recreate automatically my page and clear all my TextFields on button press.Is there a method to do it?

Comment: You can go over the link below and re-ask your question @SiegfriedMabantey https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Paste your code! We can see where to fix by using best practises of flutter. The Android implementation is different from Flutter that it store the Intent for the activity and then calls the startActivity by itself so that does not exist in Flutter by advice you paste your code its easy to fix but if you want to force it anyway go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited :**

Here is an example of how to achieve this :

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final myAController = TextEditingController();
  final myBController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  myAController.clear();
                  myBController.clear();
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Clear text fields",
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: myAController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter value A'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: myBController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter Value B'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see every time i press my flatbutton the widget reloads with the updated counter value.

[Here is an updated working demo.](https://codepen.io/FirasDev/pen/zYvmxpY)

Comment: It works well.but I don't want to use setState() because I am obligated to clear my TextField manually using this.Isn't there a method in flutter to do it automatically?

Comment: @SiegfriedMabantey i have updated my answer. check if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Firas BENMBAREK.Finally,I used setState() and it works.

Comment: @SiegfriedMabantey You're welcome, please mark the answer as correct if your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```
setState((){
  // If there is anything you want to change put it here
 });
```

This will rebuild the widget.

Comment: Share with me your code, I will see where is the problem.