# Flutter + Provider - Is it possible to restart/re-initialize a provided object?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, flutter-provider

I am having an issue where my audio engine stops working (or experiences dropouts) after being interrupted by a phone call, change to the audio output device, or other system audio events. I'd like to simply re-initialize my audio classes after such an event.

I am using a multi-Provider to provide the audio service throughout the app. I have a couple models that keep track of settings/state and could restore the state and the expected behavior after an interruption.

I considered doing something similar to the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode/50116077#50116077)

However my models and audio service are all being provided at the same level with multiprovider so any restarting of a widget tree will restart both.

I basically want to re-create my audio service with a fresh object. Any suggestions as to how to approach "restarting" a provider provided service?