# How to restart app with button in flutter

Tags: flutter, font-family

I have a setting screen, when I change **FontFamily** it needs to restart the app to change all app fonts, And it restarts after the app closed, but I want to restart the app with a button instead of closing the app. does there any way to do this ?

Comment: Hello - which IDE are you using ? VsCode ? Android Studio ? Are you running using debug mode ?

Comment: Iam using VsCode and running with debug mode

Comment: Here you will find your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: how to force an application restart (in production mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode)

Answer (score 5):

The best solution... using "Restart App" module

1. Instal from your teminal:

> `flutter pub add restart_app`

2. Import from your dart file:

> `import 'package:restart_app/restart_app.dart';`

3. Call "Restart App" from your Button:

> onPressed: () {
> Restart.restartApp();}

Have a nice day...

Comment: Just as an update, the package is updated to v1.2.0 and now it supports iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix and call Phoenix.rebirth(context); when you want to reload the app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix package in my app, to restart the app wrap widget with Phoenix on the line of code:

```
runApp(Phoenix(child: MyApp()))
```

wherever you want to restart the app just implement this line of code

```
Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```

hope this help