# Is there a way to remove all states in state management in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management, flutter-state

So currently i am using flutter [providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for managing state in my app.

Things i am able to do currently:

1. Maintaining a bool variable and using it to maintain states globally.
2. Having a string in which there is some text and it changes as user types in something and displayed on home page.

when i click on a button is there a way to erase all my maintained states to earlier one, i.e. to remove all states? I am managing lots of states for my app and it is cumbersome to manually change them to earlier one on clicking button.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116077/11149837). The top answer is by the author of the Provider package. Alternatively, you could try out the [Phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) package as suggested in another response.