# Resetting a variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hopefully this is an easy one, but I'm a complete newbie to Flutter. I'm wondering how to reset a Widget's variable to its default, say when a button is pressed. I know I can hard code it (as I have in the example below), but surely there's a smarter way to simply have it reset to its default without explicitly setting it to the same value?

Thank you for any help!

```
class WidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'widgettest_screen';
  @override
  _WidgetTestState createState() => _WidgetTestState();
}

class _WidgetTestState extends State<WidgetTest> {
  int _variable = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('$_variable'),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _variable++;
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.refresh,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _variable = 0;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Once a widget is built it doesn't really know it's "original" state until a complete rebuild of it's state occurs (i.e the application being closed). So short answer, there really isn't a way to complete what you are asking with out doing what you are already doing..

Comment: What's wrong with resetting it to 0 in the `setState` method? Or you could declare a `const _default = 10;` and then set `_variable = _default;`. A lot of extra work to create a `StatefulWidget` for a simple use case.

Comment: There’s nothing horrible with being explicit about which value it resets to. I just assumed there was a simple bit of code to go back to its original value without resetting the entire widget.

Answer (score 1):

When a `StatefulWidget` is rebuilt with a new `Key`, a new `State` is constructed.

An example implementation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116077/13458266) to a similar question.

Alternatively, the [`flutter_phoenix` package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) can be used for this purpose.

Comment: That seems like an interesting way of doing it. Resetting the whole app is a big it a sledgehammer solution, but I will look into the option of using a new Key. I must confess, I haven’t needed to delve into the subject of Keys yet, but I’d say it’s time! Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to restart the app, if you use the package it will only reset the children of the closest `Phoenix` widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
 setState(() {
                _variable = null;
              });
```