# How to restart the application or the iPad with a button using swift?

Tags: ios

I have developed an application that has a scanner to read bar codes, use a library of a private company that gave us the hardware and the library. everything works fine, but a store that has the application has power problems and for some reason causes the application to fail, the application works correctly and the next day it no longer reads codes. what we do is restart the application and it works again. then I thought that for this store to make a button to restart the application or the ipad and thus can work properly. the staff can not manipulate the iPad just by touching the screen.

but I have no idea how to do this function

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, unless things have changed since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399611/force-iphone-app-to-restart-programmatically). Have you been able to reproduce it yourself? If you can, it's probably better to identify what's causing the problem and fix that instead.

Comment: The problem is that a machine that uses a lot of voltage is used and this damages the application, because according to the specifications that the provider of the library and the scanner did not give, the voltage must not exceed 5v and at night it reaches 6.3, a solution It would be a change of site but at the moment you can not

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS.  The best you could do is force-kill the app with a button, then hope they re-launch it.  Even then, Apple might not approve the app on the App Store.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399611/force-iphone-app-to-restart-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force iphone app to restart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399611/force-iphone-app-to-restart-programmatically)

Comment: "Damages the application" doesn't really make sense. Is it corrupting the memory or something? If so, there's not really anything you can do except manually restart it unfortunately.