# Simulate a 'Home Button' click

Tags: iphone

After reading that [there is no proper way to exit an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application), is there a way to programmatically send a Home button click on the device, that would minimise the app?

"Apple developers don't do this." is an acceptable answer  :)

Thanks

Comment: "Apple developers don't do this." :)

Comment: On iOS 4, pressing the home button doesn't mean quitting the app unless you completely disable multitasking of your app.

Comment: It took KennyTM just 4 minutes to paste the most obvious answer, and Eiko 12 minutes to concisely explain why.  A heroic team effort guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Apple developers don't do this." :-)  At least when aiming for the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simulate it. But in the thread you linked to it says you can use `exit(0)` to quit the app. This won't minimise it though and it's quite likely that your app will be rejected.