# How to make a Count Down timer?

Tags: ios4

How can i start a count down timer on my application start and close application at certain time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at `NSTimer`. Read the documentation, it's not that hard to use.

When the timer fires you can exit the application. You find more information about that here:

[Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

As the most upvoted answer says, you shouldn't, but it certainly is possible.

If you need help with `NSTimer` let me know.

Comment: ok...i don't need to exit..i need to do something else.I can handle that.Please help me with something else with the timer.i want to start a timer 7:00 and count it down like 7:01-------7:60->then make it 6:00 like this finish it to 00:00.Then i will execute some method based on the tome 00:00.Can you help me about this?