# How to send application in background without pressing home button?

Tags: ios4, background

I want to send my application in background on a button's tap programmatically. How do i do that. The app goes in background when I tap on home button on iPhone but I also want the same functionality on a button's tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application). Apple doesn't like you exiting or backgrounding your application without using the home button (unless you're launching another app such as Safari).