# How to let the Program Exitting with a button?

Tags: animation, exit

How to let the Program Exitting with a button? And looks like according to "Home" button animation?

Comment: Is this iOS related? If so, tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no way to do this nicely. Apple puts that control into the hands of the user, so unless you programatically crash your app, there's no way to have a "nice" transition.

Read this answer for an explanation: [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application/356342#356342)

Comment: Thank you very much,and i know we can't do it like this,but my boss must have this function,My God.

Comment: Okay. If you want to make it crazy, how about take a screenshot of both the home screen and your application (if that's possible at all) and make a "fake" transition? I doubt it would work, though...