# xcode IOS 5 button to dismiss app like the home button

Tags: iphone, xcode, dismiss

I am writing a really simple app which should be quick to use. I therefore want to have a button that performs a function then causes the app to exit once this function is done.

Firstly is this ok with Apple's rules, the area seems a little grey.
And secondly if this is ok what code should I use? I've tried

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];

which does exit the app but I have data which needs saving on the way and this function never gets called...

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a dupe of this question:

[Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

Apple wants the user to do the quitting via the home button (look at the highly voted answer on that linked question).

Answer (score 2):

This area is not a "little grey". It's [explicitly prohibited](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html) to quit an app programmatically.

Also, `terminateWithSuccess` is a private API, so this is clearly prohibited.