# How to cancel the current view?

Tags: iphone

/* Hello,  I am learning Iphone App development. I have a doubt, in case i want to cancel the current page view and go to home page( Its nothing but cancel Button), how can i figure it out?  */

// thanks in Advance//

Comment: can you be more elaborative..your question is not clear.

Comment: OK,,  FOr example we have a Gmail login page in which we have two buttons one is Login Button and one is Cancel Button, were as "cancel" button will cancel the page and take you to home page. if i want to configure that cancel button in Iphone how can i do it?

Comment: That still isn't a question. What have you developed so far? What is the structure of your app? How are you presenting the "pages"?

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you correctly, you should use "NavigationController" like this;

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:myviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 ways to cancel view(go to home page)
1-if you are using navigationController than
try this =>     `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

2-if you are using present model view controller than
try this =>

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

3-if you are presenting the view in sub view of homepage(or like parent-child) than
try this =>    `["your view name" removeFromSuperview];`

this is useful for me i think  it may help you,

Comment: if it is like exit button( in the form of UIButton) then?

Comment: from where you want to exit? first clear this. what are you doing in your app like navigation or present view?

Comment: i want to exit out of the app, means i want to close the app and get out of it by pressing a button.

Comment: first try your own after search for your requirement  and after that you are not find anythig than ask question ok? on stack-o-flow itself you can find your answer ok on this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove your current view. If so Use [yourview removeFromSuperview];