# How To Crash An App

Tags: ios, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

How can I Crash my app?

i want To crash the app if the user press close in this code

```
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Alert!" 
                              message:@"What To Do To You App!" 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Open In Safari",nil];



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Open in Safari");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Close");
}
}
```

Comment: There are infinite ways to deliberately crash. Look at any of the questions here about crashing for useful sample code.

Comment: The simplest one: `int hellYeah = 1/0;`

Comment: [This](http://i270.photobucket.com/albums/jj105/callatov/Divided_by_zero.jpg)

Comment: its just to crash the app it the app isn't offcial version

Comment: This is The code thnx [[NSThread mainThread] exit];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use-

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit];
```

Comment: Thanks Thats Worked With ME well

Answer (score 4):

What about doing a divide by zero near to the code!

Comment: Did you mean your app can do divide by zero?!

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT add a button to close/quit your app on iOS.

Comment: I Used it to close the app if the app is cracked