# Exit button in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios6, exit

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8
                                                                                                I download this app from Apple app store.

This application also having same form which i want to implement in my application.

Registration form opens in it and having Accept and Cancel button.

when i tap on Cancel button an alert pop up shows with two buttons Yes and No.

when tap on yes app exits.

so how this app is on Apple app store.same functionality i want to perform in my iPhone Application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

Comment: You should Google or search Stackoverflow for similar questions before posting a new question. This one is really easy to find.

Comment: i have search alot for this,then only i post my question here.i know exit is not allowed by apple.then how it is used in this app.First download this app then answer https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8

Comment: Just because somebody sneaked by the app store review process doesn't mean there's an approved way to do it.  You might or might not be as lucky.

Comment: i have search alot and got almost 4-5 iPhone App which are having exit button in their iPhone.I think it is poosible that one could be lucky not all.Why Apple showing this partial behaviour

Answer (score 4):

As per apple's guidelines programmatically one should not close the application. An app should quit only when the user clicks the home button.

Comment: yaa i know this,but how exit is being used in this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8                                 i know exit is not allowed.but please download this app and then answer

Comment: Even the application verification committee will not verify each and every functionality of an app. Better be safe than sorry, as we all know how much effort we all put in it.

Comment: yes Anupdas you are rite.but how i convince my client for this..he is just forwarding me all the app links which are having exit button

Comment: I wish you good luck with that, this is something which you should figure out. You can defend yourself with numerous post saying this can be done. Once your app get rejects by committee, it will remain in their history for long time and subsequent tests are going to be even tougher. Make your client aware of many who have had a tough time to get their app up and running due to rejection.