# terminate an application when close button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a mac application in Xcode 5.1. I would like to terminate the application when the close button is clicked inside the application. Check the link for the image.

The link is as follows http://tinypic.com/r/2yn070h/8.

There is a red button on top of the window. When I click the red button the application has to be terminated. The code for termination is as follows

`[NSApp terminate:self];`

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is implement this method in your AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To exit your app use command `exit(0)`.