# Programmatically dismissing simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, applescript, ios-simulator

I know that Xcode requires the simulator to launch while running a unit test. During my CI builds, I run unit tests. Sometimes the simulator hangs up the tests, and the tests complete once I dismiss the simulator.

Is there a way to test:
1. If we are in "test mode" in the app delegate
2. If we can programatically dismiss the simulator, either as soon as it appears or after x amount of time.

I wrote an AppleScript that will quit the simulator... I suppose I could launch it from Xcode. Does anyone know how to launch a script in a method?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application

Comment: @Alex That appears to quit the app rather than the simulator

Comment: If indeed you are trying to completely quit the simulator, your AppleScript method sounds fine to me

Comment: @Alex Thank you sir. Do you happen to know how to call upon the script in a method in my App? I dragged it into my project but am unsure of how to launch the script in a specific method...

Answer (score 1):

iOS  simulator is a mac app and cannot be dismissed from an iOS app.

either you do it with apple script  or you can use a command in your build script to do that.

```
sudo killall "iOS Simulator"
```

edit: to clarify further, the script cannot be run from iOS app either. you have to call it from your build script.

Comment: Thank you sir. Do you know to call upon the AppleScript from within a class?

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with information about what is causing the failure you are trying to workaround.  Please take a sysdiagnose at the time and include ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log

As for programmatically running an AppleScript, you can do:

```
NSString *scriptSource = @"tell application ..."
NSAppleScript *script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource] autorelease];
NSError *error = nil;

[script executeAndReturnError:&error];
```

But you cannot use this from an app running within the iOS Simulator because it is isolated from the host.

Comment: Actually, it appears NSAppleScript isn't available on iOS :(

Comment: Even if it was, you would have no way of escaping the sim to communicate with the host.