# iOS: Waze exits app when user declines license agreement - how?

Tags: ios, app-store, exit

My client found that Waze app is showing License agreement to user with two buttons Decline and Accept. I am trying to tell him that best way is to have just one button and let users leave app if they don't agree with terms and conditions. But he wants to do this this way. I know that there are several ways how to quit app but I think no one will be approved by Apple in review process. So how Waze do it? When I click on Decline button app goes dark and then quits. How can this be approve in review process? Screenshot from Waze:

[image]

Comment: There is a good thread on this, and why you should not do this kind of thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

Comment: I know there are many other questions about this but I didn't see anywhere solution which would be okay with Apple and success in review process. In some apps maybe this could be overlooked but in Waze? That's what I am asking, how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Could try this,

```
import Darwin
exit(0)
```